# Cant get images to line up in td

Tags: image, html-table, inline

I am trying to get my images in my table datas to line up across the table, but when there is multi line `h5` I am struggling to figure out how to get them to line up. Its almost as if the text is like linked to the image and h6 in a way.

Here is the code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbpzJa

```
td img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you simply need to add `vertical-align: top` to TDs:

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
td img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
td h6 {
  display: inline;
}
table h5 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td>
     <img src="icon.png" />
  <h6>(Text one)</h6>
  <h5>Textline Two</h5>
   </td>
   <td>
  <img src="icon.png" />
  <h6>(Text Two)</h6>
  <h5>Long textline two long</h5>
   </td>
   <td>
  <img src="icon.png" />
  <h6>(Text one)</h6>
  <h5>Textline Two</h5>
   </td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok wow ty. Of all the things I tried this was not one of them, I was trying to use v-align on the objects inside the td, not the td itself. If I had the rep to do so I would rep you.